# How to access vue-google-chart select event on Sankey diagram in vue3?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, google-visualization, sankey-diagram

I am using vue3 with the vue-google-chart library.

I have enabled the nodes to be interactive as suggested on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/sankey).
The "onMouseOver" event works as expected, but on the select method I am missing something. I have tried several different ways to get the "clicked/selected" node from the graph unsuccessfully. Please see below.

Here is my configuration:

```
    <script setup>
    import {onMounted, ref} from 'vue'
    import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
    import { GChart } from 'vue-google-charts';
    
    const spotlight = ref()
    const is_loading = ref(true)
    const route = useRoute();
    const scan_id = ref(route.query.scan_id);
 
   
    var colors = ['#a6cee3', '#b2df8a', '#fb9a99', '#fdbf6f',
                      '#cab2d6', '#ffff99', '#1f78b4', '#33a02c'];
    const settings = ref({
        packages: ['sankey'],
    })
    var options = {
          height: 600,
          width: 800,
          tooltip: {
                isHtml: true,
                trigger: 'onmouseover',
                formatter: customTooltip,
            },
          sankey: {
            iterations:10,
            node: {
                interactivity: true,
                colors: colors,
                labelPadding: 1,
                nodePadding: 25,
                width: 30,      
                label: {
                        fontSize: 12,
                        color: '#000',
                        italic: false,
                        bold: true,
                    },
            },
        link: {
                colorMode: 'gradient',
                color: {
                        fillOpacity: 0.72,
                        stroke: 'black',  
                        strokeWidth: 0.1
                    },
            }
          }
        };
```

I have defined an eventsHandler to do different things depending on the event:

```
const chartEvents = {
  ready: () => {
    console.log("HOLA", mySankeyChart);

  },
  select: () => { 
    const selection = getSelection();
    const selection = mySankeyChart.getSelection();
    const selection = mySankeyChart.value.getSelection();
    const selectedRow = selection[0].row;
    const rowData = data.value[selectedRow];

    console.log("CLICK", selection);
    console.log("CHART", mySankeyChart);
    console.log("SELECTED ROW", selectedRow);
    console.log("ROW DATA:", rowData);
  },
  onmouseover: (event) => {
    console.log("MOUSEOVER", data.value[event.row]);
  },
};
```

On the vue3 template:

```
<template>
<GChart 
    ref="mySankeyChart"
    :data="data" 
    type="Sankey"
    :resizeDebounce="1000"
    :options="options"
    :settings="settings"
    :events="chartEvents"/>
</template>
```

[image]